# UIViewController.view.superview custom shape

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cgpath

I have a controller presenting as custom shape on iPad. Actually I have made the view itself transperent, but its subviews are visible to the user. 
I use the following code in viewWillLayoutSubviews method to make a controller with a small rectangle form:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.superView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.superview.bounds =...
```

But what if I want not a rectangle? Is there a way not to be making mind blowing CGPath for that purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you have to create a CAShapeLayer with the shape you want and then mask the view's layer with the CAShapeLayer you've created. For example, a view with a circle mask:

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150)
                                                     radius:75
                                                 startAngle:0
                                                   endAngle:M_PI * 2
                                                  clockwise:YES];


CAShapeLayer *lm = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
lm.path = aPath.CGPath;
self.view.layer.mask = lm;
```